# Spring Data Neo4j 4 SerializationException

Tags: spring, neo4j, redis, spring-data-neo4j-4, spring-data-redis

i configured Neo4j Connection as stated in neo4j documentation for spring neo4j 4.  Whenever i call save() for a Node or try to get one with a GraphRepository interface i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:166) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:128) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:85) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:409) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:331) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:211) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:193) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:169) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:127) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type  
[org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

I really don't get why redis pops in.I need it for redishttpsession. I don't modify anything for Redis so far.Only config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.test.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConnectionConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration{

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jConnectionConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Override
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer(){
    log.info("Initialising Server Connection");
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474","neo4j","password");
}

@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    log.info("Initializing Session Factory");
    return new SessionFactory("com.test.domain");
}

@Override
@Bean
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception{
    log.info("Initializing session scoped session Bean");
    return super.getSession();
}
}
```

nothing is persisted. How can i fix this.

Edit:

Entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class UserNode {

@GraphId
private long nodeId;

private Long externalId;

@Relationship(type="FRIEND",direction=Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
private Set<UserNode> user = new HashSet<UserNode>(0);

public UserNode(){}

public UserNode(Long externalId){
    this.externalId = externalId;
}
}
```

Git: https://github.com/CeryniTheRat/neo4jredisdemo  sample project with same error

Comment: What does your entity look like?

Comment: Hmm. Looks legit to me. Any way you could share your code (privately)? BTW, the @GraphId has to be a Long (not long)

Comment: if i remove any redis dependency it works but i dont get why it fails with redis connection (so far i didnt find equaly named Beans or smth. and i can get my Principal if i want to without any error)

Comment: @Luanne added git link any idea? (forgot to mention you with @ before)

Comment: No clue as to why this is failing. The SDN code looks fine. Will have to investigate some more

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-794 to track this issue